# Multiple references to a Ball object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game like pong with multiple power-ups. One of them is to have a "Triple Ball" power-up. I tried just creating another reference of the ball, but that doesn't seem to work. I figured this would work because I mostly work with Java where I can just create another instance. Here is how I tried to do it, I tried testing through just clicking a button:

```
public class TripleBall : MonoBehaviour {

    public Ball firstBall;
    private int amountOfBalls = 2;
    private Ball[] ballArray;
    private bool start, avail, located;

    void Start () {
         ballArray = new Ball[amountOfBalls - 1];
         for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length; i++)
              ballArray[i] = new Ball();
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
            start = true;
        if (start)
        {
            //Begin locator: Makes it so when the balls spawn they spawn where the first ball
            if (!located) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    ballArray[i].transform.position = firstBall.transform.position;
                }
                located = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems I can't do this because Ball is of type MonoBehavior.

Is there any way to do this the way I planned or any way at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't use `new` to create an instance. The only place you are right in your code is using new to initialize array. After that, you are supposed to use `GameObject.AddComponent` to create a new instance instead of the `new` keyword. This is because Ball class derives from the `MonoBehaviour`.

You `Ball` class derives from `MonoBehaviour`.

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

Here is your code fixed:

```
   private Ball[] ballArray;

    void Start()
    {
        ballArray = new Ball[amountOfBalls - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < ballArray.Length; i++)
            ballArray[i] = gameObject.AddComponent<Ball>();
    }
```

Assuming that your `Ball` class looks like the code below and does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`:

```
public class Ball
{

}
```

Then code in your question would be valid and using new is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use instantiate. It is derived from Unity's Object class, so assuming "ball" inherits from either Object or GameObject, this is what you want. You can find more info about it here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html